# Making template display data on load

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm trying to make my template display data from the component when it is loaded. I have tried using the *ngIf condition set to object that is being loaded in itself.

So like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody *ngIf="country">
        <tr>
            <td>{{country.name}}</td>
            <td>{{country.population}}</td>
            <td>{{country.area}}</td>
            <td>{{country.language}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, nothing is being displayed on the page.
This is what my component looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BackendService } from 'src/app/backend.service';
import { ICountry } from '../interfaces/country';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-countrydetails',
  templateUrl: './countrydetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./countrydetails.component.css']
})
export class CountrydetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  public country: ICountry;

  constructor(private _backendService: BackendService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCountry(this.router.url.replace('/',''));
  }

  getCountry(country: string): void {
    this._backendService.getCountry(country).subscribe(data => {
      this.country = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

What should I do to make the template display my data when the object is no longer undefined?

{{country|json}}

```
{ "country": { "name": "Russia", "capital": "Moscow", "language": "Russian", "population": "144526636", "density": "8.4", "area": "3969100", "majorCities": [ { "name": "Moscow", "population": "12506468", "area": "2562", "rank": "1" }, { "name": "Saint Petersburg", "population": "5351935", "area": "1439", "rank": "2" }, { "name": "Novosibirsk", "population": "1473754", "area": "503", "rank": "3" } ] } }
```

Comment: does `console.log(data)` show the data being returned from the `getCountry()` service call?

Comment: Yes, it returns the object.

Comment: if you add {{country | json}} outside of your table in the template, does that show up?

Comment: @Edward Yes, then it does show up.

Comment: where is your `table` tag? is it defined in a parent component or is it missing from your template on purpose?

Comment: @Edward Sorry, forgot the tags, but it seems to make no difference. I will update my og post.

Comment: if you are seeing the data when you add `{{country | json}}` but not in your table, is it possible that the data being returned is not in the format you think it should be? i.e. if you use the inspector, do you actually see the columns being added in the HTML, but just not the values?  can you paste the output you are getting from the service?

Comment: @Edward How do I go about sharing that? Sorry, new to angular.

Comment: copy and paste the output you see in the template from when you added `{{country | json}}` to your html

Comment: @Edward updated og post once more

Comment: something else must be off, everything appears correct. can you create a stackblitz example to reproduce the issue? I've created a dummy example here -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gq7h9g?file=src/app/app.component.ts. you can modify it and let me know, or create one yourself and share it

Comment: @Edward I found the issue. It had to do with the REST function which returned the object within curly brackets. Removing those solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should store in `country` an observable of your `BackendService`.

```
public country: Observable<ICountry>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.country = this.getCountry(...);
}

getCountry(country: String): Observable<ICountry> {
  return this._backendService.getCountry(country);
}
```

And then, in your HTML component

```html
<tbody *ngIf="country | async as country">
    <tr>
        <td>{{country.name}}</td>
        <td>{{country.population}}</td>
        <td>{{country.area}}</td>
        <td>{{country.language}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I'm still having the same issue of nothing being rendered on the page. However, the tbody and tds are being drawn.

Comment: this answer doesn't do anything to address the OP issue. merely a different way of subscribing to the observable